# SQL Query to Find Overlapping Dates in Separate Rows and Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to check Phase Dates that are stored in separate columns in a Table, to report when any Date from a follow-on Phase overlaps the prior Phase Date.

Below is information on what I am attempting with my actual data, but based on made-up data. Hoping that this will help, I have provided this as consumable test data, rather than listing data in an on-page Table format:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    REC_ID char(4) NOT NULL
    ,ITEM_ID CHAR(4) NOT NULL
    ,PHASE_NAME varchar(10) NOT NULL
    ,PHASE_A date NULL
    ,PHASE_B date NULL
    ,PHASE_C date NULL
    ,PHASE_D date NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (REC_ID, PHASE_NAME)
);
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('0001', 'ab05', 'Phase A', '20220201', NULL, NULL, NULL)
    ,('0001', 'ab10', 'Phase B', NULL, '20220202', NULL, NULL)
    ,('0001', 'ab03', 'Phase C', NULL, NULL,'20220101', NULL)
    ,('0001', 'ab99', 'Phase D', NULL, NULL, NULL, '20220203')
    ,('0002', 'cn00', 'Phase A', '20211201', NULL, NULL, NULL)
    ,('0002', 'cn34', 'Phase B', NULL, '20211120', NULL, NULL)
    ,('0002', 'cn07', 'Phase C', NULL, NULL, '20211203', NULL)
    ,('0002', 'cn55', 'Phase D', NULL, NULL, NULL, '20211202');
```

Please note that the 'Item_ID' is a very long system generated Global Unique Identifer (GUID), so it is probably not a good candidate for sorting purposes.

Note that each of the Phase Dates are captured in their own column. As such, as an example, the 'Phase_B' column Date needs to be compared with the 'Phase_A' Column Date.

Finally, to make it even more complicated, the results need to be captured to their own columns to support the error validation reporting that is needed.

To help clarify this, I have attempted to detail below the type of target table output that I need below:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmptgt
(
    REC_ID char(4) NOT NULL
    ,ITEM_ID CHAR(4) NOT NULL
    ,PHASE_NAME varchar(10) NOT NULL
    ,PHASE_A date NULL
    ,PHASE_B date NULL
    ,PHASE_C date NULL
    ,PHASE_D date NULL
    ,PH_B_OL_PH_A varchar(14) NULL
    ,PH_C_OL_PH_A varchar(14) NULL
    ,PH_D_OL_PH_A varchar(14) NULL
    ,PH_C_OL_PH_B varchar(14) NULL
    ,PH_D_OL_PH_B varchar(14) NULL
    ,PH_D_OL_PH_C varchar(14) NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (REC_ID, PHASE_NAME)
);
INSERT INTO #tmptgt
VALUES ('0001', 'ab05', 'Phase A', '20220201', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass')
    ,('0001', 'ab10', 'Phase B', NULL, '20220202', NULL, NULL, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass')
    ,('0001', 'ab03', 'Phase C', NULL, NULL,'20220101', NULL, 'Pass', 'PhC Olps PhA', 'Pass', 'PhC Olps Ph', 'Pass', 'Pass')
    ,('0001', 'ab99', 'Phase D', NULL, NULL, NULL, '20220203', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass')
    ,('0002', 'cn00', 'Phase A', '20211201', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'PhB Olps PhA', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass')
    ,('0002', 'cn34', 'Phase B', NULL, '20211120', NULL, NULL, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass')
    ,('0002', 'cn07', 'Phase C', NULL, NULL, '20211203', NULL, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass')
    ,('0002', 'cn55', 'Phase D', NULL, NULL, NULL, '20211202', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass', 'PhD Olps PhC');
```

I am not certain if this type of combined overlapping date checking and feedback layout is possible, but that is what is required to support our reporting needs and I would certainly appreciate feedback.

Comment: "One issue I have is that I am working in a secure environment and I therefore need to generate sample pseudo-data to try to explain the need." - this is true of everyone - all questions should be a [mre] not the real data.

Comment: Just FYI: Guids are fine for sorting, as long as they are stored as Guids (and not strings). They are far better than strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the dates on a row with a conditional MAX OVER.
And then it becomes easy to compare the dates per phase.

> ```
> SELECT REC_ID, ITEM_ID, PHASE_NAME 
> , PHASE_A , PHASE_B , PHASE_C , PHASE_D 
> , CASE 
>   WHEN PHASE_NAME LIKE '%B' AND B < A
>   THEN 'PhB Olps PhA' 
>   ELSE 'Pass' 
>   END AS PH_B_OL_PH_A
> , CASE 
>   WHEN PHASE_NAME LIKE '%C' AND C < A
>   THEN 'PhC Olps PhA' 
>   ELSE 'Pass' 
>   END AS PH_C_OL_PH_A
> , CASE 
>   WHEN PHASE_NAME LIKE '%D' AND D < A
>   THEN 'PhD Olps PhA' 
>   ELSE 'Pass' 
>   END AS PH_D_OL_PH_A
> , CASE 
>   WHEN PHASE_NAME LIKE '%C' AND C < B
>   THEN 'PhC Olps PhB' 
>   ELSE 'Pass' 
>   END AS PH_C_OL_PH_B
> , CASE 
>   WHEN PHASE_NAME LIKE '%D' AND D < B
>   THEN 'PhD Olps PhB' 
>   ELSE 'Pass' 
>   END AS PH_D_OL_PH_B
> , CASE 
>   WHEN PHASE_NAME LIKE '%D' AND D < C
>   THEN 'PhD Olps PhC' 
>   ELSE 'Pass' 
>   END AS PH_D_OL_PH_C
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT *
>   , MAX(CASE WHEN PHASE_NAME LIKE '%A' THEN PHASE_A END) OVER (PARTITION BY REC_ID) AS A
>   , MAX(CASE WHEN PHASE_NAME LIKE '%B' THEN PHASE_B END) OVER (PARTITION BY REC_ID) AS B
>   , MAX(CASE WHEN PHASE_NAME LIKE '%C' THEN PHASE_C END) OVER (PARTITION BY REC_ID) AS C
>   , MAX(CASE WHEN PHASE_NAME LIKE '%D' THEN PHASE_D END) OVER (PARTITION BY REC_ID) AS D
>   FROM #temp
> ) q
> ORDER BY rec_id, phase_name;
> ```

> | REC_ID | ITEM_ID | PHASE_NAME | PHASE_A | PHASE_B | PHASE_C | PHASE_D | PH_B_OL_PH_A | PH_C_OL_PH_A | PH_D_OL_PH_A | PH_C_OL_PH_B | PH_D_OL_PH_B | PH_D_OL_PH_C |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0001 | ab05 | Phase A | 2022-02-01 | *null* | *null* | *null* | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
> | 0001 | ab10 | Phase B | *null* | 2022-02-02 | *null* | *null* | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
> | 0001 | ab03 | Phase C | *null* | *null* | 2022-01-01 | *null* | Pass | PhC Olps PhA | Pass | PhC Olps PhB | Pass | Pass |
> | 0001 | ab99 | Phase D | *null* | *null* | *null* | 2022-02-03 | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
> | 0002 | cn00 | Phase A | 2021-12-01 | *null* | *null* | *null* | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
> | 0002 | cn34 | Phase B | *null* | 2021-11-20 | *null* | *null* | PhB Olps PhA | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
> | 0002 | cn07 | Phase C | *null* | *null* | 2021-12-03 | *null* | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
> | 0002 | cn55 | Phase D | *null* | *null* | *null* | 2021-12-02 | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | PhD Olps PhC |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4fed3cbab60b15f857f61a72ecf5a13)*

Comment: Hi @LukStorms  A quick note of appreciatation for you taking the time to review my need and produce the sample code, along with the demo on Fiddle. This was all extremely helpful.
Just as important, I was able to review the output of each session of the code and improve my admittedly limited understanding of such SQL code. I now understand how the "OVER (PARTITION BY REC_ID)" portion of the code structures the dates so that the are comparible by row.
Having struggled with this for some time, thanks so much for providng me with the solution to my overlapping dates check.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to gather up the dates into a single record, after which the validity tests may be more easily applied and combined with the original data. Try something like:

```
SELECT T.*,
    Check1 = CASE WHEN D.DateA < D.DateB THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Oops' END,
    Check2 = CASE WHEN D.DateA < D.DateC THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Oops' END,
    ...
FROM #temp T
JOIN (
    SELECT REC_ID,
        DateA = MAX(PHASE_A),
        DateB = MAX(PHASE_B),
        DateC = MAX(PHASE_C),
        DateD = MAX(PHASE_D)
    FROM #Temp
    GROUP BY REC_ID
) D ON D.REC_ID = T.REC_ID
```

Comment: A good answer explains the techniques used in addition to containing working code.

Comment: T N, thanks for your feedback on my overlapping dates request. This helped with my understanding of the process, supporting that which was really clarified by @LukStorms code and Fiddle demo.